# Input 5 numbers then show all the positive and negative that you entered

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, subtraction

I'm getting 0 instead of 1 1 1 1 1.

**class learn**

```
package learn2;
import java.io.*;

public class learn {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

            InputStreamReader ISR=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ISR);

             int myArray[]=new int[5];
                 int sum= 0;
             int pro = 0;

             for(int u=0;u<5;u++)
             {
                 if (myArray[u]>0)

                 {

             sum= sum= sum = myArray[u];
            pro = pro* myArray[u];

                     }

            System.out.println("enter a number");
            String x=br.readLine();
              int x1=Integer.parseInt(x);

             myArray[u]=x1;

             }
                 for (int u1=0;u1<5;u1++)
             {      
                 System.out.println("You Enter" + myArray[u1] );
                 }


               System.out.print("the sum of all positive numbers is:  " + sum );
              System.out.println("the product of all positive numbers is: " + pro);
    }

}
```

Comment: I can see your output, but was was the input? And btw, what is the question?

Comment: the program supposed to show the negative and positive that you
 enter. but my program shows 0 whatever i put a number

Comment: You're performing the addition and multiplication steps *before* you read the numbers in, when the values are still zero by default.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. Do `sum = sum + myArray[u];` instead of `sum= sum= sum = myArray[u];`
2. Multiply something with 0 is always 0, so initialize pro with 1: `int pro = 1;`
3. Do the calculation after reading the first value in your for-loop because you are testing `myArray[u]>0` and `myArray[u]` is always 0 if you test it before reading.

   ```
    for(int u=0;u<5;u++)
    {
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        String x=br.readLine();
        int x1=Integer.parseInt(x);
        myArray[u]=x1;

        if (myArray[u]>0)
        {
            sum= sum + myArray[u];
            pro = pro* myArray[u];
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: thank you bro. i learn something. btw the output should be. like this.

Comment: it should be. sorry. im new here. dont know the function yet
enter a number 1
enter a number -1
enter a number 1
enter a number 2
enter a number -2
the sum and product of all positive numbers is: 4
the product of all positive numbers is:

Answer (score 0):

You're getting 0 because in Java the default values of `int` array is 0, for all elements. And since you're summing and multiplying the elements **before** you read the input, you're getting 0.

You should do:

```
for(int u=0;u<5;u++) {
    System.out.println("enter a number");
    String x=br.readLine();
    int x1=Integer.parseInt(x);

    myArray[u]=x1;
    if (myArray[u]>0) {
        sum+= myArray[u];
        pro = pro* myArray[u];
    }
}
```

More changes:

- Initialize `pro` to 1, not to 0, as it's a multiplication
- Chagne `sum= sum= sum = myArray[u];` to `sum += myArray[u];`

Now you're fine.

Comment: thank you bro. sorry im kinda new here
but the loop is set to 5. and the output should be
enter a number 1 
enter a number -1 
enter a number 1 
enter a number 2 
enter a number -2
the sum of all positive numbers is: 4
the product of all positive numbers is: 2